# What's the meaning the code block between line 169 and line 171 in async.js?

Tags: javascript, async.js

The code block is

```
if (completed >= arr.length) {
   return callback();
}
```

It is in the function _eachLimit.

My thought is that since JavaScript is single-threaded, the callback function which is in the parameter list of iterator function can be executed only once at a time, so situation that **completed** variable can not be modified by two callback function simultaneously. And if so, when callback function is called,  it will check the **completed** variable every time so that it can end the while loop.

And the code block above seems like it is redundant, so what's the use of the code block?

Thanks a lot for answering my question.

The whole function is as below:

```
var _eachLimit = function (limit) {

    return function (arr, iterator, callback) {
        callback = callback || function () {};
        if (!arr.length || limit <= 0) {
            return callback();
        }
        var completed = 0;
        var started = 0;
        var running = 0;

        (function replenish () {
            if (completed >= arr.length) {
                return callback();
            }

            while (running < limit && started < arr.length) {
                started += 1;
                running += 1;
                iterator(arr[started - 1], function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        callback(err);
                        callback = function () {};
                    }
                    else {
                        completed += 1;
                        running -= 1;
                        if (completed >= arr.length) {
                            callback();
                        }
                        else {
                            replenish();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        })();
    };
};
```

Comment: Might be a recursive function? I don't know, it's impossible to tell with so little code ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Indeed it's recursive, see here: https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/async.js @ L:157. kg8gk, I can't see redundancy here. Could you please explain yourself a tad bit better? Perhaps I misunderstood you.

Comment: How would it know it completed if not for that piece of code?

Comment: Why are you asking SO, and not the maintainers of this code? They would know best.

Comment: @iccthedral I can't figure out the use of the code block, why there? why another `completed >= arr.length` check in the beginning of replenish function?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol already answered, `replenish` is a recursive function; and that `if` block that you think is redundant is really necessary for it to stop eating your stack. Other check is under `else` block which is yet under `while` block, so it might not execute.

Comment: @iccthedral but if the condition does not satisfied the `while` loop, the recursive function would not be executed.

Comment: @iccthedral, `replenish()` is not recursive, calling yourself from an asynchronous callback does not accumulate stack space. `replenish()` calls itself from the callback passed to `iterator()`, which seems to be async, so the stack will be clean.

Comment: I apologize for spreading misinformation. Frederic, I see it now, and kg8gk, yes - you're right. I was out of my mind.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I still have questions and commented under your answer..

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Would you mind seeing my comment one more time? I've wrote a gist

Answer (score 1):

From the code you posted, it seems you want to know why `completed` is checked against `arr.length` twice: both at the start of `replenish()` and from the callback function passed to `iterator()`.

Javascript is indeed single-threaded (in browsers) (so far), but `iterator()` is *asynchronous*. It will return immediately and invoke the provided callback function some time later, and by that time `completed` and/or `arr.length` *might have changed even though a single thread has run*, so another check is indeed necessary.

Comment: Suppose that the asynchronous operations in iterator  come to an end and iterator calls the **callback** (the 2nd parameter of iterator), and it goes back to the javascript environment, single-threaded. In my mind that the callbacks one by one, and if so, the variable **completed** would not be changed by other callbacks since only one callback can be executed at a time...I'm faint with the code block now T.T

Comment: @kg8gk, I don't think I understand your comment. The point in my answer was that `completed` can have changed between the first check in `replenish()` and the time the callback is invoked.

Comment: What means is the **callback** in your comment, the second argument of iterator, or the callback of the returned function(the 3rd argument of it)? If it is the former one, I thought it does not matter, because `completed` only can be changed in the callback,  and without error, it would be checked every time when the execution goes into the first `else` clause in the callback.

Comment: And here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/kg8gk/7355295) about my thought of the process..